# Why does the Roboto font look different when used with the LaTeX package?

Tags: fonts

I'm using the LaTeX package `roboto` in the way that is proposed [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/robotoregular/):

```
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

The output (pdflatex) looks like this:

[image: latex roboto]

However, the 'real' Roboto font looks like this (see [here](http://typecast.com/preview/google/Roboto), for example):

[image: real font]

The general quality might be a sampling problem but you can notice small differences like the square vs. round 'i'-dot or the way that the 'r' or the 'e' looks like in the comparison:

[image: comparison]

Is there a way to get the 'proper' Roboto font or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: https://publicobject.com/2014/06/26/roboto-old-and-new/  The package uses the old version of the font.

Comment: You can use the new version of the font if you have it installed on your system and then load it with `fontspec` and compile using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX.

Comment: I guess that an email to Bob Tennent (the maintainer of the Roboto font distribution for `pdflatex`) is in order.

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you very much for the link: this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @egreg I will write an email to Bob Tennent and ask him about it. Thank you.

Comment: @Thérèse Can you provide an answer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Robot comes in two versions, both of which may be seen and downloaded at [publicobject.com/2014/06/26/roboto-old-and-new/](https://publicobject.com/2014/06/26/roboto-old-and-new/).  For a far more elaborate comparison, see the review by Stephen Coles, “Roboto <strike>Is</strike> Was a Four-headed Frankenfont,” at [typographica.org](http://typographica.org/on-typography/roboto-typeface-is-a-four-headed-frankenstein/).

For now, the package `roboto` supplies the older version of the font. Users of `luatex` or `xetex` may dispense with the package, install the new font on their systems (downloading it from the link above or, of course, from [www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto)), and invoke it with `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setsansfont{Roboto}`.

Comment: As suggested, I wrote an Email to Bob Tennent and he immediately updated the package on CTAN: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/roboto. It now includes the newest version of Roboto!

Comment: @shark.dp I confirm that the font has the new shapes in TL2015/pretest, so TeX Live 2015 will sport it by default.