# Strikeout in roboto font in texlive 2015

Tags: units, strikeout

In `texlive 2015` strike through for roboto font is a bit too high for lower case letters.
I think the reason might be, that the unit `1ex` for this font differs roughly by a factor 2 from what I would expect.
I found, that I can redefine `ex` with \fontdimen5\font, however it seems to just change the value for the current font size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}

\sout{hello world}

\newlength{\totalheightofex}
\setlength{\totalheightofex}{\totalheightof{x}}
Height of x \the\totalheightofex

\newlength{\oneex}
\setlength{\oneex}{1ex}
Height of 1ex \the\oneex

\fontdimen5\font=5.34pt
\sout{hello world}

\setlength{\totalheightofex}{\totalheightof{x}}
Height of x \the\totalheightofex

\setlength{\oneex}{1ex}
Height of 1ex \the\oneex

\large{
\sout{hello world}

\setlength{\totalheightofex}{\totalheightof{x}}
Height of x \the\totalheightofex

\setlength{\oneex}{1ex}
Height of 1ex \the\oneex
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of pdflatex in texlive 2015]

I guess, it would be possible to define a custom strikeout, but I would prefer to change the `ex` unit.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I forgot to tell that Bob Tennent, the maintainer of the package, is usually very prompt in fixing bugs; you can reach him by email, the address is in the README file: http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/roboto/README

Comment: Problem solved! See addition to answer! `:-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's clearly a bug in the font metric files, I think it's a regression because the parameters were good in TeX Live 2014.
However, the fonts were changed in the transition to TeX Live 2015 (see [Why does the Roboto font look different when used with the LaTeX package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238979/why-does-the-roboto-font-look-different-when-used-with-the-latex-package)) and the new metric files are faulty. You can somewhat cure it by changing the command executed each time a font of the family is loaded, so it sets correctly the x-height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\AtBeginDocument{\normalfont % force loading of the fd file
  % reset the x-height at each call of a font
  \expandafter\gdef\csname\encodingdefault+Roboto-LF\endcsname{%
    \fontdimen5\font=\fontcharht\font`x }%
  % also for the normal font
  \fontdimen5\font=\fontcharht\font`x
}

\newlength{\heightofex}
\newlength{\oneex}

\begin{document}

\sout{hello world}

\settoheight{\heightofex}{x}
Height of x \the\heightofex

\setlength{\oneex}{1ex}
Height of 1ex \the\oneex

\large
\sout{hello world}

\settoheight{\heightofex}{x}
Height of x \the\heightofex

\setlength{\oneex}{1ex}
Height of 1ex \the\oneex

\end{document}
```

However it's a kludge and the font metric information should be fixed in the TFM files by the package maintainer.

[image]

---

## UPDATE: Problem solved!

With today's (2015-09-18) update to TeX Live, containing `roboto` revision 38386, the following document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\newlength{\heightofex}
\newlength{\oneex}

\begin{document}

\sout{hello world}

\settoheight{\heightofex}{x}
Height of x \the\heightofex

\setlength{\oneex}{1ex}
Height of 1ex \the\oneex

\large
\sout{hello world}

\settoheight{\heightofex}{x}
Height of x \the\heightofex

\setlength{\oneex}{1ex}
Height of 1ex \the\oneex

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

The height of ‘x’ is not the same as 1ex, but this is the font designer's choice.